# jquery addClass to trigger

Tags: jquery

I have a set of trigger divs that on click animate up the nearest div named `.animatePanel`.

I have the following jQuery but I want to add a class to the click trigger (`.panelTab`) when the animated panel is shown as well as the class that is being applied to the animated panel.

```
$('.panelTab').click(function() {
  var panel = $(this).next()
  $('.animatedPanel').removeClass('active');
  $('.animatedPanel').not(panel).slideUp();
  panel.addClass('active').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: So you want class active to also trigger the click event?

Comment: Hi Travis, 

At the moment when I click the trigger div it animates up a div named animatedPanel, but also applies a class of active to it. 

I want to also apply a class to the trigger (.panelTab) when it's clicked.

Comment: Inside of the click "trigger" (technical term is a callback or callback function :D ) `this` will refer to the native JavaScript element which was clicked. If you wish to add a class to that, you may pass it to the jQuery constructor using `$(this)`, and then access jQuery's API (such as addClass) by using `$(this).addClass('ApplySomeClassNameToClickedElement')`.

Comment: sorry, cut myself off there. 

Normally i'd do something like:

$(this).toggleClass('.active') but understand that won't work

Comment: Is that what you had in mind, or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Keep in mind, you want to only use the `.MyClassName` as a selector (note the `.`). When toggling classes, you would omit that part, and use `$(this).toggleClass('active')`.

Comment: @Geoff when do you want to add a class to the .panelTab element? After the animation has been done? or before that?

Comment: Hi DivakarDass, before or at same time as animation if good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.panelTab').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('someClass');
  var panel = $(this).next()
  $('.animatedPanel').removeClass('active');
  $('.animatedPanel').not(panel).slideUp();
  panel.addClass('active').slideToggle({
  direction: "up"
  }, 100);
});
```

It sounds like you just want to apply addClass to the clicked panelTab. So you can use `$(this)` within that listener to access the clicked panelTab.

Were you looking for something more complex?

Like perhaps removing "someClass" from all panelTab class before adding it to the clicked one?

```
within the listener...
$('.panelTab').removeClass("someClass");
$(this).addClass("someClass");
..
```

Comment: Hi Kai, 
This is fine for adding the class BUT if the user clicks trigger A, then the hidden panel slides up and .active class is added to the trigger but if they click another trigger (I have 5 triggers animated different divs) then the active trigger stays with the first and also is added to the second. I need the .active class to be removed if the animated panel is closed ect

Comment: Hi Kai, Sorry just realised a small problem. If I click trigger one the class is added, then if I click another trigger its removed from the last one and added to the new trigger. Thats perfect BUT if you click trigger 1 (or any other) then click the same trigger to close it does not remove the active class.

Comment: Right. It looks like the little addition I posted would handle that. You just remove all of the active classes to the panelTab class before assing it to the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
$('.panelTab').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  var panel = $(this).next()
  $('.animatedPanel').removeClass('active');
  $('.animatedPanel').not(panel).slideUp();
  panel.addClass('active').slideToggle({
  direction: "up"
  }, 100);
});
```

Edit :

```
 $('.panelTab').click(function() {
      // this removeClass will remove active state of all panelTab elements.
      $('.panelTab').removeClass('active');
      // Then this will add active class only to that trigger. So you will have only one active trigger.
      $(this).addClass('active');
      var panel = $(this).next()
      $('.animatedPanel').removeClass('active');
      $('.animatedPanel').not(panel).slideUp();
      panel.addClass('active').slideToggle({
      direction: "up"
      }, 100);
    });
```

Comment: Hi DvakarDass, 

Please see my response to Kai as your suggestion was the same :)

Comment: @Geoff If i have understood you right. Then i think you need to use removeClass for .panelTab so it removes all active classes from that and then you need to use $(this).addClass('active'). See my updated answer.